# Win8 periodic tile notifications - shorter than half hour?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winjs

The [PeriodicUpdateRecurrence enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.periodicupdaterecurrence.aspx) has 5 values, from half an hour to daily. Does this mean you can't set any other (shorter) values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to battery life concerns, intervals shorter than 30 minutes are not possible for periodic tile notifications. If your app tile needs to be updated in real-time, consider using push notifications.

The following Windows blog post provides details about battery life with respect to push notifications (which apply to periodic updates as well):
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/11/02/updating-live-tiles-without-draining-your-battery.aspx

MSDN article on the different notification delivery methods:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779721.aspx